# PHP - continue/break for loop it current loop takes more than x seconds

Tags: php

I am processing some data using for loop (100 records) in PHP. I am calling APIs in the loop, most of the time all records are processed in expected time. But sometime any single loop can take so much time because of waiting api response which just increases the overall processing time significantly.

Is there any way in php to "continue" the loop if it takes more than x seconds for the any single loop, so that we can just process overall records in expected time at the cost of few unprocessed records?

Comment: Without a code example it will be difficult to help you. Add some code, it does not have to be the real code but it must demonstrate your situation and requirements. An answer will depend on what you are actually doing in your loop

Comment: If you're using curl, you can set a timeout (CURLOPT_TIMEOUT). The request will be killed after the timeout and you'll continue the processing

Comment: My code is much more complex, I am selecting records, calling multiple api's, checking into database multiple times, inserting into db into multiple tables. I can't afford more than 10 seconds for a single loop element, 90% of records are processed quickly only few of them are sometime bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CURL to call the API, you can check `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` and `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` (ref [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)).
Otherwise it isn't so easy to realize. You should create a multi-threaded environment, with one worker thread running the execution of your loop and another thread that checks if the execution is taking too long.

Comment: This solution is good, but sometime it takes time to insert into mysql db because other scripts are inserting into the same table.